# How to confgure multi realm Kerberos

Tags: authentication, kerberos, user-accounts, sssd, cross-domain

### Intention

I want to set up 2 Kerberos realms where one can authenticate the users in the other.

### Current Setup

I have 2 Kerberos Servers (`ad.somedomain.com` and `kerb.foo.bar`)

I have my users on `kerb.foo.bar`

| User |
| --- |
| user1 |
| alice |
| bob |

I can `kinit user1@KERB.FOO.BAR` , `alice@KERB.FOO.BAR` and `bob@KERB.FOO.BAR` and get **tgt** for all of them when I `klist`.

##### I want

I want to use the `AD.SOMEDOMAIN.COM` as a sub realm or the `ad.somedomain.com` as an intermediate server.

I want to be able to `kinit user1@AD.SOMEDOMAIN.COM`, `alice@AD.SOMEDOMAIN.COM` or `bob@AD.SOMEDOMAIN.COM` and have it grant tickets and authenticate.

```
  ad.somedomain.com ←→ kerb.foo.bar
          ↑
user1@ad.somedomain.com
```

##### Clarification

I am unsure of how to:

1. Set up the trust relationship between `ad.somedomain.com` and `kerb.foo.bar`
2. How to setup the users in such a way to allow what I want to accomplish
3. How to set up the client `krb5.conf` to properly use this setup.
4. (*Optional*) Is there a difference in setting this up as a "one-way" trust?

   I don't think I need this relationship to happen in reverse:
   Where I have users in `ad.somedomain.com` that I want authenticated in `kerb.foo.bar`

##### What I have done

I have looked at this part of the [MIT Documentation on Kerberos](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.5/krb5-1.5.4/doc/krb5-admin/Cross_002drealm-Authentication.html) but I must be doing something wrong.

It might be that my `krb5.conf` is set up incorrectly or that I have my `[capaths]` wrong.

##### `krb5.conf`

```
[libdefaults]
 forwardable = true
 default_realm = KERB.FOO.BAR
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
 KERB.FOO.BAR = {
  kdc = kerb.foo.bar
  admin_server = kerb.foo.bar
 }
 AD.SOMEDOMAIN.COM = {
  kdc = ad.somedomain.com
  admin_server = ad.somedomain.com
 }

[domain_realm]
 .ad.somedomain.com = AD.SOMEDOMAIN.COM
 ad.somedomain.com = AD.SOMEDOMAIN.COM
 .kerb.foo.bar = KERB.FOO.BAR
 kerb.foo.bar = KERB.FOO.BAR

[capaths]
  AD.SOMEDOMAIN.COM = {
    KERB.FOO.BAR = .
  }
```

Comment: Is your realm named `kerb.foo.bar` or `KERB.FOO.BAR`? There's a difference. (Realm names are case-sensitive and traditionally upper-case; even in AD the realm name is upper-case even though the UPN suffix is lower-case.)

Comment: Yes.
My realm is `KERB.FOO.BAR` and the dns domain the Kerberos server is running on is `kerb.foo.bar`.
Which parts of my question should I change to uppercase to avoid confusion?